# C++ behaviour during hex constant bit shifting

Tags: c++, bit-shift

Why is the following expression evaluated as `0xFFFFFFFFFF000000`, instead of `0x00000000FF000000`? How can I get `0x00000000FF000000`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h> // uint64_t
#include <iomanip>  // std::setfill, std::setw

#define hexLOG(x) std::cout << std::showbase << std::internal << std::hex << std::uppercase << (x) << std::nouppercase << std::dec << std::endl;

int main ()
{

    hexLOG(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF & (0xFF << (8 * 3)));

    return 0;
}
```

### Update:

I have create the following example so that you can see the difference between the two methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h> // uint64_t
#include <iomanip>  // std::setfill, std::setw

#define hexLOG(x) std::cout << std::showbase << std::internal << std::hex << std::uppercase << (x) << std::nouppercase << std::dec << std::endl;

int main ()
{
    uint64_t mask = 0xFF;

    hexLOG("   mask:", (mask << 56));
    hexLOG("   mask:", (0xFFu << 56));
    hexLOG("   mask:", (0xFFull << 56));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason here is that `0xFF` is a 32-bit `signed int` and `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF` is probably a 64-bit `signed long long` on your platform. When you perform the `&` operation, the shifted `0xFF` (which at the time will hold the value `0xFF000000`) gets promoted to 64-bit `signed long long`, at which point sign-extension takes place to preserve the fact that `0xFF000000` represents a negative number on your platform.

In general, left-shifting a positive `signed` integer such that the sign bit is affected is undefined behaviour. You should normally use `unsigned` types for bit shifting operations. You can add the `u` suffix to the end of your hex literals to make them unsigned literals: `0xFFu`.

Comment: That's the answer. Thanks for prompting me to get to the bottom of the difference in the generated code and to refresh my aging (non-ecc) memory.

Comment: You are right, but if I use the `u` at the end of hex literals I don't get the result I want. I still need to use @enhzflep method...

Comment: @user3379939 Really? It works for me. I get `0xFF000000` as the output when I do: `hexLOG(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFul & (0xFFu << (8 * 3)));` What does your code look like?

Comment: On another piece of code, while in this example i get the same result. If I use `0xFFull`, I get the right one, in the other example too, but I am not sure if it's `C++14` compliant. I'll try to create a MWE...

Answer (score 2):

It's a signed/unsigned issue. By default, (from memory) a constant is of type int. 
EDIT: Further to the comments I've looked deeper and of course, I was wrong. As pointed out by Jordan Melo, Slava and molbdnilo, the issue isn't as a result of sign extension of the number, but rather, one of integer promotion.

Here's the solution:

```
#include <iostream>

#define hexLOG(x) std::cout << std::showbase << std::internal << std::hex << std::uppercase << (x) << std::nouppercase << std::dec << std::endl;

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int inputVar = 0xFF;

    hexLOG(0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF & (inputVar << (8 * 3)));

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the difference caused by the signed keyword on the resulting assembly:

**Signed int**

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push    rbx
    sub rsp, 24
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 255
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
    sal eax, 24
    movsx   rbx, eax      ; mov 32bit eax into 64 bit rbx with sign extension
```

**Unsigned int**

```
main:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push    rbx
    sub rsp, 24
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-20], 255
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-20]
    sal eax, 24
    mov ebx, eax          ; mov 32 bit eax into 32 bit ebx
```

Comment: Thanks. What's strange to me, is that I knew that for left-shift operations you just always add zeros at the right. While for right-shift operations you have two options, arithmetic and logical shift. So, since I am left shifting I thought that it couldn't be a sign replication problem.

Comment: This answer is not correct. Sign extension never takes place with a left shift.

Comment: @JordanMelo - Have you tried to run the provided code, removing the unsigned keyword from the variable declaration? GCC says otherwise.

Comment: @enhzflep I am certain that the issue is related to signed types, but I am also certain that it's *not* related to left-shifting.

Comment: @enhzflep Jordan Melo is rights, issue is not left shift but if result of left shift unsigned or signed int. You can check that by casting result of left shift operation to unsigned int instead of changing 0xFF.

Comment: The sign extension isn't caused by the left-shifting but by the integer promotion.